# Ext JS Hash Map not being destroyed after window closes

Tags: javascript, extjs

Basically just want to create a new hashmap once the window is closed because it currently will still have the old values after closing and rendering a new window.

```
 data: {
     classCheck: false,
     hashTable: new Ext.util.HashMap(),
     countValid: 0
  }

 listeners: {
       afterrender: function() {
          var scope = this;
           window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
               scope.updateWindow(scope);
           });

           this.on('close', function(scope) {
               this.getViewModel().data.hashTable = new Ext.util.HashMap();
               window.removeEventListener('resize', scope.updateWindow);
          });
     },

  },


  renderer: function(value, cell_field1, cell_field2, cell_field3) {
           var hashmap = this.up('classroom').getViewModel().data.hashTable;
```

Comment: Don't poke the underlying data property of the view model. Use the `get` and `set` methods.

Comment: Can you help me understand what you mean? I used getViewModel()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript uses [prototyping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) to implement class inheritance. The windows are instances of a window class, and due to the nature of prototyping the window instances reference the properties defined on the class until an instance explicitly sets them.

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.Class', {
    boolean: true,
    object: {},

    constructor: function() {
        /* 1. Instance  Prototype
              {         {
                          boolean: true,
                          object: {}
              }         }
        */

        this.boolean = false;
        this.object.key = false;
        this.object = {};
        /* 2. Instance                Prototype
              {                       {
                boolean: false,         boolean: true,
                object: { key: true }   object: { key: false },
                                        instance: null
              }                       }
        */

        // This returns true.
        return this.object.key;
    }
});
```

Therefore, the window instances need to set the values of properties that are objects or arrays during initialization, so that each instance gets its own copy. This can be defined on the class, and it is usually done in the constructor so that the data is available as early as possible.

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.window.Window', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    data: null,

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.data = {
            classCheck: false,
            hashTable: new Ext.util.HashMap(),
            countValid: 0
        };

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```